# Blender Fluid simulation for larger areas?

Tags: fluid-simulation, mantaflow

I have a room with a pipe on the ceiling that water has to drip down from. For this reason I have to make the domain accordingly to the bottom that the water comes up and splashes there. But because this makes the domain very large, the water is extremely crumbly and low-resolution even at a resolution of 800. Unfortunately, my PC can't get any higher and I have an i9 12900k and an rtx 3090..

And so the backing times are really a disaster. Do you have any experience of what can be done to implement something like this? Actually ridiculous, I only need a small jet of water that comes down from the ceiling and that this requires such an enormous amount of computing power or is not feasible at all, isn't it absurd??

Thanks

Comment: please show us a sketch how it should look like. Often you could try to make more domains and "merge" the simulations together by example given a camera change. If you want a continuous camera i think then you won' t have another chance than increasing resolution. By the way: for every computer the baking time will get a desaster if the domain is just that big and the resolution is high...

Comment: Hey there, that´s a good idea but unfortunately i have an continious camera. I don´t have a sketch at the moment but it´s very simple. Just water dropping from a pipe in the ceiling to the ground. Now i made the domain as little as possible and the resolution to 1000 and so it works at least. But god damn that Baking Times are crazy..